# Angular - Rails No route matches api/versioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing a rails 4.1.8 API and using angular js in the client side but in a different workspace. I'm using grunt-connect-proxy to proxy all request to my rails API but Rails is always returning me `No route matches[METHOD]"ROUTE"` but trying with the Advance Rest Client works well i don't know what i'm going wrong.
the domains aren't the problem, they are working

routes.rb

```
namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: {subdomain: 'api'}, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      with_options except: [:edit, :new] do |except|
        except.resources :users do
          collection do
            post 'login'
          end
        end
        except.resources :products
        except.resources :locations
      end
    end
end
```

my angular code looks like this

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $resource) {
    var User = $resource('/v1/users',{},{});
    User.get().$promise.then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
```

and this is my Grunt proxy configuration

```
grunt.initConfig({
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    hostname: 'dev.myapp.co',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  proxies: [
    {
      context: '/v1',
      host: 'api.myapp.co',
      port: 3000
    }
  ],
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest,
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  ...
  });
  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
  if (target === 'dist') {
    return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
  }

  grunt.task.run([
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:server',
    'autoprefixer',
    'configureProxies',
    'connect:livereload',
    'watch'
  ]);
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-connect-proxy');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a sneaking suspicion that you may have incorrectly named your Rails controllers. Do you mind posting either `user_controller`, `product_controller`, or `location_controller`? Thanks!

Also, what happens when you attempt to access the api directly by `localhost:3000/v1/users`? Do you get the same `No route matches[METHOD]"ROUTE"` error?

Comment: i am using sub domains, so when i call http://api.DOMAIN:3000/v1/users it works, the rails controllers are ok, i'm using rspec to test them and all is right, i don't know what's going on with the proxy